# S3 – Images sometimes showing up with wrong rotations

Tags: python, django

I run a web service where users are allowed to upload images.

I've noticed that sometimes, the uploaded image on S3 shows up rotated – as I came to learn due to exif metadata.

Taking a sample of some of the images, and opening them in GIMP, it yields a prompt where I have to decide whether to keep or strip the exif metadata.

I noticed, however, that sometimes the "properly" rotated image includes the exif metadata, and, other times, to "properly" rotate the image I need to tell GIMP to ignore the exif data.

I thought I could resolve this issue simply by getting rid of the exif metadata, but this will not work under the above observation.

**So, in summary:** **how can I guarantee image uploading to S3 with the correct image rotation?**

P.S.: I am using Python via boto3 to upload images.

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the tags because the problem has nothing to do with S3 or boto3. S3 does not change the content of data you upload

Comment: That is true, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is the easiest option:

```
from PIL import ImageOps

with Image.open(image_path) as image:
    image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)
```

This should automatically correct the rotation of your image.